# Conversion of English into Urdu or arabic

Tags: php

How to Convert the  English text in other languages like Urdu in php code?

I want to convert the English database values in Urdu so which library i should use for this purpose.

Comment: use google translation API

Comment: Try to use this:- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/12/30/easy-php-site-translation/

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use "Google Translate" integrated to site, but that conversion is not 100% perfect. 
There are other tools too. http://jquery.bunkerhill.com/
Try this, it is good.